# Superfish sf-navbar issue in internet explorer 7,8,9

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I am using Superfish menu for my DNN website and applying sf-navbar as a class for ul by using jquery in superfish.js. I think this is not a right way to include it! However, I have also defined the superfish-navbar.css in menudef.xml.

The second problem is when the menu loads in any browser, for some seconds it show white colour  as a border on each li items in the menu. I am not able to figure out where is this problem coming from.

This are the links to my website: [www.siddharthkpandey.co.uk/museum/newdesign.aspx](http://www.siddharthkpandey.co.uk/museum/newdesign.aspx) and [www.siddharthkpandey.co.uk/museum/newdesign/generalpage.aspx](http://www.siddharthkpandey.co.uk/museum/newdesign/generalpage.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On  superfish.css, line 62, you are having `.sf-menu a` which is the problem.

This is how I tracked it:

1. Open chrome
2. [Disable javascript in chrome](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/iVovbbwnu5E)
3. go to http://www.siddharthkpandey.co.uk/museum/newdesign.aspx
4. right click any item in menu and click no inspect element.

enable javascript again when you get this fixed. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: it worked for me. I did that on my localhost but still I need to update on my real skin file. thanks